# Android: Range Slider: Gettting range slider value

Tags: android, addeventlistener, rangeslider

> All I am looking to do is get the value of the range slider, there is just not enough documentation to assist me so hopefully someone can assist me if you be so kind. Thank you!

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
RangeSlider rangeSlider;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Slider rangeSlider = (findViewById(R.id.slider));


    /*-- [(START)Get Range Slider Value] --*/
    float apple = rangeSlider.getValue();

    Log.i(apple);



    rangeSlider.addOnChangeListener(new Slider.OnChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(@NonNull Slider slider, float value, boolean fromUser) {
        float b = rangeSlider.getValue();

        }
    });

    /*-- [(END)Get Range Slider Value] --*/

}
```

}

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stepSize="5"
        android:value="50"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="100"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.499" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

> float b = rangeSlider.getValue();

Isn't float b, the value you are expecting ?
Log the float value and check

Comment: Exactly, but it won't let me pass the float value which is weird....

Comment: can you share your xml definition of the activity that has rangeslider ?  want to see if it is the standard one or something else you are using

Comment: Added as requested,

Answer (score 0):

Android Toast Message Is Not Showing in Emulator || toast not working in android studio 2021

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dWMuPqsHekg

Preety much the answer to the question is that Android is buggy creature. I did the steps as instructed and now it works. AWD Manager > Actions> Wipe Data > Yes

Thank you to everyone for trying to assist me, I appreciate the effort made. :)